# What spells are available to heal characters, increase their max HP, or grant temporary HP?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing, hit-points

I'm trying to work out a healer multi-classed build and want to make sure I'm not missing any options. Please give references to the locations that the spells were found in. Unearthed Arcana is fine.

Spells that restore HP, increase max HP, or give temporary HP are specifically the type of spells that are being asked for.

Comment: Question shows lack of research

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Hence why I'm asking the question, an efficient method of gaining the information I desire. Aka: research

Comment: @TheAussieSlime I think what Korvin was getting at was that this is a question that basically boils down to: "do this annoying task for me". It's not that you didn't know how to do something it's just that you wanted other people to do it for you. Such questions are often looked down upon here.

Comment: You got an answer that will likely be useful to others as well.

Comment: Thanks for the question. Since this website appears on google when questions are asked, it is a very useful resource for other people wanting to know the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Here are the spells with healing powers

All spells listed below are available in the basic rules unless otherwise marked.

- [Aid](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aid)
- [Armor of Agathys](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/armor-of-agathys) (PHB)
- [Aura of Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aura-of-life) (PHB)
- [Aura of Vitality](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/aura-of-vitality) (PHB)
- [Beacon of Hope](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/beacon-of-hope)
- [Cure Wounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/cure-wounds)
- [Enervation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enervation) (XGE)
- [False Life](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/false-life)
- [Goodberry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/goodberry)
- [Greater Restoration](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/greater-restoration)
- [Heal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heal)
- Healing Elixir ([UA](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf))
- [Healing Spirit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-spirit) (XGE)
- [Healing Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/healing-word)
- [Heroes' Feast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heroes-feast)
- [Heroism](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/heroism)
- [Life Transference](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/life-transference) (XGE)
- [Mass Cure Wounds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-cure-wounds)
- [Mass Heal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-heal)
- [Mass Healing Word](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/mass-healing-word)
- [Power Word Heal](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/power-word-heal) (PHB)
- [Prayer of Healing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prayer-of-healing)
- [Raise Dead](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/raise-dead)
- [Regenerate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/regenerate)
- [Reincarnate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/reincarnate)
- [Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/resurrection)
- [Revivify](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/revivify)
- [Soul Cage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/soul-cage) (XGE)
- [Spare the Dying](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spare-the-dying)
- [True Resurrection](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-resurrection)
- [Vampiric Touch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch)
- Virtue ([UA](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UA-Starter-Spells.pdf))
- [Wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)

[This search](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells?filter-class=0&filter-search=&filter-tags=2) on D&DBeyond produces many (but not all) of these spells.

Comment: @TheAussieSlime changing the links is not a problem effort-wise for me, however if the material is required to be purchased (which means that the material is not in the basic rules/SRD) then linking to another site that provides it is piracy which is something that is not only unethical by also [disallowed by site policy](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/links-to-dd-tools-dndtools-eu-and-similar-sites/2773#2773). All the links going to the basic rules versions of the spells above should be freely accessible to all, but do let me know if there is an issue with them.

Comment: @TheAussieSlime I would also note that dnd5e.wikia.com is also a very unreliable source apart from the other issues. In fact we just this morning had a question which was caused by the text quoted by that site being wrong. I have found this to be a common source of issues actually. So that would be another objection I would have to using it as a source (and also a caution to you in case you depended on it as your only source as well).

Comment: All the PHB & XGE content are unavailable to the public (essentially, any book title; anything that's not open5e/SRD). None of the XGE or PHB links work. Since 5e "spell description" text is part of its effects, we can't cite each spell's effects, without linking to paywalls. Plus, their text cannot legally be reproduced here, except under Fair Use; Q\A regarding Armor Of Agathys, Aura Of Life/Vitality, Enervation, Healing Spirit, Life Transference, Power Word Heal, Soul Cage, etc, can quote those contents to comment upon\criticize\parody them; but can't reproduce them for reference use...! 