# Are there any feats that increase hit points?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, hit-points

My character has the lowest hit points in our party (I mean he is even lower than the Artificer of the party, and I am a Fighter), so I was wondering if there were any feats that increase max hit points. I am moreso looking for one that increases hit points permanently.

---

This is another question that is similar but different from this one that I asked:
[Is there any magic item that increases Hit Points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185291/is-there-any-magic-item-that-increases-hit-points)

Comment: Have you looked at the feats? Is there something you're not finding?

Comment: Yeah, just want to know which one will do the best job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## *Tough* or *Inspiring Leader*

I agree that the *Tough* feat is the most effective at raising an individual PC's Hit Point maximum (PHB, p.170). It is the equivalent of a +4 to Constitution, without the benefit to saving throws and other game mechanics such as *holding breath*.

There are other feats that provide +1 to Constitution:

- Aberrant Dragonmark, ERLW p.52
- Durable, PHB p.166
- Dwarven Fortitude, for *dwarves* XGE, p.74
- Infernal Constitution, for *tieflings* XGE, p.75

There are also feats that provide you with an option of choosing +1 Constitution:

- Chef, TCE p.79
- Crusher, TCE p.79
- Dragon Fear, for *dragonborn* XGE p.74
- Dragon Hide, for *dragonborn* XGE p.74
- Orcish Fury, for *half-orcs* XGE p.75
- Resilient, PHB p.168
- Second Chance, for *halflings* XGE p.75
- Skill Expert, TCE p.80
- Tavern Brawler, PHB p.170

It's also worth pointing out that the feat that can potentially increase the most amount of Hit Points for the greatest number of characters in a party of six is: ***Inspiring Leader*** (PHB, p.167)!

A 20th level character with the *Tough* feat will have an additional +40 hit points.

A 20th level character using *Insipiring Leader* on a party of six with a Charisma score of 20 (+5), would provide: 25 Hit Points to *each* character; so 150 temporary Hit Points for a party of six.

The characters can benefit from this feat **after a short or a long rest**. So potentially, in most campaigns where players choose to have 1 long-rest and 2 short-rests. This would mean that each PC could get +75 Hit Points over a day's time, and it would be wopping 450 Hit Points in total if all six party members benefit.

You do need to consider where you pool your ability points though as at lower levels to get the most out of *Inspiring Leader* the character that uses it needs to have a high Charisma score. This is not always a bad option though as it will have good synergy with the Intimidation skill which if you are proficient in can prevent you from even having to fight in the first place. If you are lucky, you might be able to talk a player with a high CHA score in your group into taking this feat.

Lastly, I think it's important to note that, because you are a Fighter, it may be worth considering a combination of increasing your maximum or temporary pool of Hit Points as well as working on getting a high *Armour Class*. The AC may save your bacon more than a large pool of Hit Points because the creatures might not even be able to hit you. If you are subject to lots of critical hits it may be worth considering Adamantine Armour as well as this will turn a critical hit into a normal hit (DMG, p.150).

Answer (score 15):

The [Tough](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/tough) feat (PHB, p. 170) is exactly what you want:

> Your hit point maximum increases by an amount equal to twice your level when you gain this feat. Whenever you gain a level thereafter, your hit point maximum increases by an additional 2 hit points.

On the [other Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/185291/is-there-any-magic-item-that-increases-health), plenty of people gave you advice on increasing your Constitution, which is also an option with feats, but if that's your goal, it'd be better to just use your next ASI to do that directly instead of taking a feat.

Comment: The problem with using ASI instead of feats (Not including magic items to increase ability scores) is that our characters in our campaign wont be leveling up much, our DM uses leveling by milestone so we don't us XP and we instead level up when we beat a common goal, so changing in an ability for a score that won't be used often would be a great help. Thanks though, @L Cooper!

Comment: @MikeZ.: I don't see how slow leveling is relevant here; feats are an option instead of ASIs, but (aside from Variant Human's free first level feat), they're both equally available.

Comment: Well the thing is @ShadowRanger we are leveling really slow so if I get an ASI then I get a plus one to health every level up isn't going to do much compared to getting the Tough feat which gives me 12 hit points and 2 more every level up, so how my campaign is going, a feat is much more useful.